# How do I save values from a List<string> to an Excel worksheet using EPPLus

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.5

I'm trying to save values from a `List<string>` to a Excel Worksheet using EPPlus so I wrote this code:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int value = bdCleanList.Count() / Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text);
        string bases_generadas = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "bases_generadas");

        var package = new ExcelPackage();

        package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("L1");
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        worksheet.Name = "L1";

        int j = 2;
        int col = 1;

        for (int i = 1; i < bdCleanList.Count(); i++)
        {
            if (i%Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text) == 0)
            {
                package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("L" + j);
                worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[j];
                worksheet.Name = "L" + j;
                j += 1;

                worksheet.Cells[i, col].Value = bdCleanList[i];
            }
            else
            {
                worksheet.Cells[i, col].Value = bdCleanList[i];
            }
        }

        Byte[] bin = package.GetAsByteArray();
        File.WriteAllBytes(System.IO.Path.Combine(bases_generadas, "bases_generadas_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx"), bin);

        MessageBox.Show("Se generaron un total de " + value + " bases y puede encontrarlas en la siguiente ruta: " + System.IO.Path.Combine(bases_generadas, "bases_generadas_" + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString() + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy-hh-mm-ss") + ".xlsx"), "Información", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    }
```

In the sample I'm running `bdCleanList.Count()` has 2056 values, Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text) has 500 as value so `value` gets in this case *5*, the problem here is that values for L2, L3 ... L5 aren't saved and I don't know why. Values for first worksheet is saved fine but the rest don't, what's wrong in my code? How do I set active worksheet in order to save values on the active sheet? How do I move between worksheets?

Comment: This is a bad title. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title

Comment: i don't know if this is right but from just looking at this I assume you need `j.toString()`

Comment: @SonerGönül better now?

Comment: @Sayse `j.toString()` where? values for first worksheet are saved well but for the rest not, that's my problem

Comment: you have `add("L1")` and then in your loop you are searching through and `add("L" + J)` and same for name

Comment: @sayse I don't understand you. I create my first worksheet outside the cycle because is the first sheet where I save values, then inside the cycle I check if `i%500 = 0` and if so then add a new worksheet, this part works fine. Values from `bdCleanList()` are added right too to the first worksheet (L1) but for the rest L2, L3 and so on it doesn't

Comment: nvm just read you can add integers to strings

Comment: @Sayse honestly I don't follow you, could you please write a answer with some code sample to see what are you saying?

Comment: any help on this? I can't find any docs related to this on Google :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, after some days of headache and a lot of hours reading my code once and once and finding over Internet I found the solution: my code was "good" but I didn't get the mistake until I debug it line by line several times. If yours see in this line `worksheet.Cells[i, col].Value = bdCleanList[i];` is where I set values for Cells and it does but for **L1** and because `i` start at `0` and then I wrote in `(i+1)` all was good, Cells start in 1 and end in 499, then for **L2** and because I don't scroll to the end of Column, values start in Cell 500 and end on Cell 1000, and this is right because `i` was on 500 at the moment where L2 was created. That was the problem. So I change my code to this one:

```
        int pos = 1;

        for (int i = 0; i < bdCleanList.Count(); i++)
        {
            if ((i + 1) % Int32.Parse(textBox7.Text) == 0)
            {
                package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("B" + j);
                worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[j];
                worksheet.Name = "B" + j;

                j += 1;
                pos = 1;
            }

            worksheet.Cells[pos, 1].Value = bdCleanList[i];
            pos++;
        }
```

And that does the job as I want. Thanks to every people here for try to help me